# creating multi band raster from one GeoTiff

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, envi

I'm using AgiSoft photoscan to create a photo mosaic from aerial images. The images are being captured using a camera modified for NIR and RGB data capture.

I want to be able to perform spectral mixture analysis on the image using a package like ENVI but am unsure where to start or if this is even possible.

I assume that I would need to first create a mutli band raster from the single exported ortho GeoTIFF from Agisoft Photoscan. But even this I'm not sure about. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: What do you mean by single geotiff? Do you have a separate geotiff for each R,  G,  B &  N band?

Comment: It's just one GeoTiff from the photo processing software.

Answer (score 1):

ENVI can handle this directly. there is a layer stacking tool (Basic Tools > Layer Stacking) to create composite bands.

Comment: Thanks :) I've done this for the GeoTiff and have an output file. Where should I go to next to start analysing the image? I'm sorry about the newbie question. Do you know of any good resources? I ultimately want to perform spectral mixture analysis on the data.